# Automated process for using .csv to create a chart/graph then embed to SharePoint site

Tags: file-upload, chart, csv, schedule, office-graph

*Disclaimer: First, I am a student worker that has limited experience with coding.  I am not sure how much of this process can be solved this way.  Second, I recently started using SharePoint so I'm not sure if embedding the graph/chart at the end needs to have any special requirements.  Finally, hopefully this is in the right spot because it presumably uses things that aren't just in SharePoint but I would like the end result to be viewed in SharePoint so it made sense to post this here.*

At my school we have a reporting tool that can automatically generate .csv files from our financial system.  My task is to come up with some framework as to how we can get this data to automatically upload and embed into a SharePoint 2013 site after using the data to create a visualization (chart/graph).  This is what we're envisioning:

1. The report (.csv file) will be automatically generated at X time each day and downloaded to a local folder.  This part I know what to do and how to do it.  One potential problem: how do I automatically delete files from the previous day before the next one is downloaded?
2. The downloaded .csv file will need to be uploaded to *something* that generates a basic graph or chart based on some predefined criteria.  **I do not know what program/coding to use for this.**
3. The graph/chart needs to be automatically embedded/reloaded in the SharePoint 2013 site.  This part seems straightforward enough, but I'm not sure if there are any specific requirements when using SharePoint.

Once this is all set up, they don’t want any human interaction with the process, allowing it to go on each day and automatically update the charts on the site.  My overall question is: how do I accomplish this?  What programs/sites/coding/etc. do I need to use?  Will there be a cost factor or is everything I can use free?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat extensive topic to come with a solid answer for.

There exist a variety of already built-in Excel service functionality supporting what you are asking for - and I would suggest trying looking into those options.
We don't know the setup of your reporting tool or its capabilities; or your SharePoint setup for that matter.

Let's say you go with the Excel service option.

- To load the `.csv` or `.xlsx` into SharePoint, you need a service to pick it up and upload it to SharePoint.
- You need the reporting tool to spit out an `.xlsx` file with already defined charts with names, showing data from specific columns.

  - Or you can keep the `.csv` but have the service picking up the file for SharePoint do some Excel magic creating these charts.
- You need a SharePoint page to be setup with web parts showing the various charts (which are only available with the Enterprise version - unless you're using SharePoint Online)

  - Here's a youtube video on how to setup the web parts: [Add Live Graph To SharePoint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsWLIX__XEk)

This is what you roughly need to have in order and do to make the framework work independently of human interaction.